# IE7 rendering and javascript differences between 7.0.5730.13CO vs 7.0.5730.13

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, rendering

I have a site a client is trying to use that doesnt work on their machine using IE7 version 7.0.5730.13CO. We know it works on version 7.0.5730.13 with all. By 'work' I mean it renders different and the javascript functions differently.

I found a [site](http://www.activewidgets.com/javascript.forum.22538.8/ie-7-0-5730-13co.html) (basically the only site I could find on google about it) that said the CO was for Corporate Administrator.

When you edit with Microsoft's [IEAK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/bb219517.aspx) it seems to add this CO.

How can I find out what changes were applied to the clients machine? I can do a remote desktop sharing with them if needed.

Unfortunately I cannot upload any sample code because of my contract.

Comment: Just in case anyone else has issues like this, it turns out it wasn't the version at all causing the problems. It was the DPI being set high or the Font Size being set to Large in the Windows settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This "CO" version is not a separate Microsoft release.  It is just an indication that the "official" IE version 7.0.5730.13 was customized using the [**IE Administration Kit** (IEAK)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/bb219517.aspx) by some administrator at this customer's site.  Another 7.0.5730.13CO from another site could be completely different, as it depends on the options chosen with the kit.

If you need to test with this particular version, you need to obtain the distribution stream or whatever media/approach they use at this particular site to push-out IE (and other) updates.

This may be a question better directed at serverfault.com or maybe supersuser.com

You can learn more online with the "IEAK", "Administrator Kit", keywords, or also by using just "CO" and/or "CO suffix" rather than trying to search for this very version number.